# What do I have to do in order to get a cauldron Pixelmon 3.4 server running using Multicraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-pixelmon

Currently I am running a server that has pixelmon 3.3.8. I am now trying to update the version of pixelmon to 3.4 (the newest one). It was running fine with 3.3.8 so I swapped out 3.3.8 for 3.4. No every time I try to run the server I get this: http://prntscr.com/690lme and http://prntscr.com/690m6y and it doesnt open the server.

Comment: Posting the actual log (even to someplace like http://pastebin.com/) would be a big help over screenshots.

Comment: There is not enough information with the current screenshots to see the problem. Please post the full log, as @MBraedley mentioned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [requesting **technical support on getting modded Minecraft to run**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797). We allow an exception for unmodded or 'Vanilla' Minecraft, please see [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9943/4797)